# How do you reify/walk a record definition in Haskell

Tags: generics, haskell, template-haskell

Given an record (not an instance of the record, the record definition itself) such as:

```
data Request
    = Expand { shortUrl :: [String]
             , hash     :: [String]
             }
    | Shorten { longUrl :: String
              , domain  :: String
              }
    | LinkEdit { link     :: String
               , title    :: Maybe String
               , note     :: Maybe String
               , private  :: Maybe Bool
               , user_ts  :: Maybe Int
               , archived :: Maybe Bool
               , edit     :: [String]
               }
```

how does one generate code using info from the record definition -- e.g.,:

```
mkReqUrl :: Request -> String
mkReqUrl (Expand shortUrl hash)   = mru "expand"  (zr "shortUrl"  [shortUrl] ++ zr "hash"   [hash])
mkReqUrl (Shorten longUrl domain) = mru "shorten" (zr "longUrl"   [longUrl]  ++ zr "domain" [domain])
...
```

I imagine some usage of TemplateHaskell and a generics library (e.g., Uniplate) might do the trick.  (I have peaked at
the Lens implementation since it deals with record definitions, but I get lost in the code.).

Answer (score 3):

[GHC.Generics](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/GHC-Generics.html) (actually, the docs for the version that will ship with GHC 7.8 are probably a better read; see below) is probably the way to do this now. First derive a [`Generic`](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/GHC-Generics.html#t%3aGeneric) instance for your type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
data Request =  ...
     deriving Generic
```

You can then use `from` to convert your value to its generic representation type, and apply `selName` to the appropriate part of that structure (one of the `S1 Blah_blah Foo...` bits).

I'll leave that last part as an exercise for you; the structure of the `Rep` types are super byzantine. Although it looks like it will be well-documented in the new GHC [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.1-rc2/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.0/GHC-Generics.html).

Comment: Thanks.  That is useful.  But what I am most curious about is how to reify a DECLARATION, not a value.  Reifying an ADT declaration seems to be easy in TH (see my answer to my question).   It it also possible with GHC.Generics (or Uniplate)?

Answer (score 1):

**How to reify using Template Haskell**

(the following has been hand-edited to make it easier to read)

```
> ghci -XTemplateHaskell
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
...
Prelude> :m + Language.Haskell.TH
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> :{
data Request
  = Expand { shortUrl :: [String]
           , hash     :: [String]
           }
  | Shorten { longUrl :: String
            , domain  :: String
            }
  | LinkEdit { link     :: String
             , title    :: Maybe String
             , note     :: Maybe String
             , private  :: Maybe Bool
             , user_ts  :: Maybe Int
             , archived :: Maybe Bool
             , edit     :: [String]
             }
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH| :}
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> $(stringE . show =<< reify ''Request)
...
"TyConI (DataD [] :Interactive.Request []
         [RecC :Interactive.Expand   [(:Interactive.shortUrl,NotStrict,AppT ListT (ConT GHC.Base.String))
                                     ,(:Interactive.hash,NotStrict,AppT ListT (ConT GHC.Base.String))]
         ,RecC :Interactive.Shorten  [(:Interactive.longUrl,NotStrict,ConT GHC.Base.String)
                                     ,(:Interactive.domain,NotStrict,ConT GHC.Base.String)]
         ,RecC :Interactive.LinkEdit [(:Interactive.link,NotStrict,ConT GHC.Base.String)
                                     ,(:Interactive.title,NotStrict,AppT (ConT Data.Maybe.Maybe) (ConT GHC.Base.String))
                                     ,(:Interactive.note,NotStrict,AppT (ConT Data.Maybe.Maybe) (ConT GHC.Base.String))
                                     ,(:Interactive.private,NotStrict,AppT (ConT Data.Maybe.Maybe) (ConT GHC.Types.Bool))
                                     ,(:Interactive.user_ts,NotStrict,AppT (ConT Data.Maybe.Maybe) (ConT GHC.Types.Int))
                                     ,(:Interactive.archived,NotStrict,AppT (ConT Data.Maybe.Maybe) (ConT GHC.Types.Bool))
                                     ,(:Interactive.edit,NotStrict,AppT ListT (ConT GHC.Base.String))]]
         [])"
```

One can then walk the structure returned from `reify` using standard recursion/pattern matching.